# Macro behind constructor. What does it mean?

Tags: c++

```
#define _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE
class out_of_range : public logic_error 
{
public:
    explicit out_of_range(const string& __arg)_GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE;
};
```

What does _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard committee has some groups that research and propose some experimental features. One of these is the transactional Memory study group (SG5). Their main work result is [Technical Specification for C++ Extensions for Transactional Memory](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4514.pdf). You can read a simple version on [Transactional memory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory).

Part of this proposal is a `transaction_safe` function specifier. So your function would be:

```
class out_of_range : public logic_error 
{
public:
    explicit out_of_range(const string& __arg) transaction_safe;
};
```

Note that `transaction_safe` is a keyword.

The macro just conditionally defines this specifier if capabilities are met. E.g. taken from [here](https://gitlab.indel.ch/thirdparty/gcc/commit/13143e139230dc4d72710a6c4c312105aeddce4f):

```
// Conditionally enable annotations for the Transactional Memory TS on C++11.
// Most of the following conditions are due to limitations in the current
// implementation.
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L && _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI            \
  && _GLIBCXX_USE_DUAL_ABI && __cpp_transactional_memory >= 201505L \
  &&  !_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING && __GXX_WEAK__            \
  && _GLIBCXX_USE_ALLOCATOR_NEW
#define _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE transaction_safe
#define _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN transaction_safe_dynamic
#else
#define _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE
#define _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN
#endif
```